# Issue with try-finally in Scala

Tags: scala, exception

I have following scala code:

```
val file = new FileReader("myfile.txt")
try {
 // do operations on file
} finally {
  file.close() // close the file
}
```

How do I handle FileNotFoundException thrown when I read the file? If I put that line inside try block, I am not able to access the file variable inside finally.

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **scala** **2.13**:
you can just use `Using` to acquire some *resource* and `release` it automatically without error handling if it's an `AutoClosable`:

```
import java.io.FileReader
import scala.util.Using

val newStyle: Try[String] = Using(new FileReader("myfile.txt")) { 
  reader: FileReader =>
    // do something with reader
    "something"
}
newStyle
// will be 
// Failure(java.io.FileNotFoundException: myfile.txt (No such file or directory))
// if file is not found or Success with some value it will not fall
```

**scala 2.12**:

You can wrap your reader creation by `scala.util.Try` and if it will fall on creation you will get `Failure` with `FileNotFoundException` inside.

```
import java.io.FileReader
import scala.util.Try

val oldStyle: Try[String] = Try{
  val file = new FileReader("myfile.txt")
  try {
    // do operations on file
    "something"
  } finally {
    file.close() // close the file
  }
}
oldStyle
// will be 
// Failure(java.io.FileNotFoundException: myfile.txt (No such file or directory))
// or Success with your result of file reading inside
```

I recommend not to use `try ... catch` blocks in scala code. It's not type safety for some cases and can lead to non-obvious results but for release some resource in old scala versions there is the only way to do it -  using `try`-`finally`.

Comment: You can use **Try** to release resources, you can also use appropriate resource management datatypes like `cats.effect.Resource` or `zio.ZManaged`.